# How to set output file mode permissions (rw-rw-rw-)

Tags: c, output, chmod

I've created a code that should be able to copy a file a user suggests. What I am wondering is this: how do I set the output file mode and how do I determine what the output file mode permissions will be in this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char c;
char source_file, target_file;
FILE *in, *out;

printf("Enter name of file to copy\n");
   gets(source_file);
printf("Enter name of file to copy to\n");
  gets(target_file);
in = (source, O_RDONLY);
out = (target_file, O_CREAT|WRONLY, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH);

/* error handing */
if( in == NULL )
{
   printf("Error. \n");
   exit(0);
}

printf("Enter the copied file name \n");
gets(target_file);

out = fopen(target_file, "w");

/*error handing*/
if( out == NULL )
{
  fclose(in);
  printf("File opening error.\n");
  exit(0);
}

while(( c = fgetc(in) ) != EOF )
  fputc(c,out);

fclose(in);
fclose(out);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: You already know how to change the mode, you have it as one of your tags to this question. For the other, to get file permissions, use [`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html).

Comment: Would this be as simple as adding in a chmod(out, 666) somewhere before I close the file?

Comment: Except that [`chmod`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html) doesn't take a `FILE*` argument. Instead you can use `fchmod` in tandem with [`fileno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html).

Comment: Please don't use `gets()`, even in toy programs.  It is lethal; it is a very bad habit to get into.  Use `fgets()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

#### Controlling file permissions using standard I/O

One of the demerits of the standard I/O library is that you can't control the permissions on the files that are created, primarily because such permissions are rather platform-specific (more so than the C standard allows for, anyway).  The POSIX [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) function allows you to control the permissions on the file as it is created.

With a POSIX-like system, you can use the [`chmod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chmod.html) or [`fchmod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchmod.html) system calls.  You need to know that your `rw-rw-rw-` pattern is octal 0666.

```
chmod(target_file, 0666);
fchmod(fileno(out), 0666);
```

The functions can fail; you should check that they don't.

You can also use the [`umask()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/umask.html) function or (with care) the [`umask`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/umask.html) command to influence the default permissions.  For example, setting `umask 022` in the shell means that files will not be created that are writable by group or others.

---

#### Revising the modified code

1. You don't need to worry about the permissions on a file you open for reading (or, at least, you seldom need to do so).
2. Worrying about the permissions on the file you write to is more normal.
3. Your current code proposal is:

   ```
   in = (source, O_RDONLY);
   out = (target_file, O_CREAT|WRONLY, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH);
   ```

   This does not invoke `open()`, and assigns an integer value to the two `FILE *` variables, which should be generating compiler warnings.  Note that the comma expressions evaluate the LHS and then the RHS of the expression, yielding the RHS as the overall value.  `O_RDONLY` is classically 0; the combination of `S_IRUSR` etc terms is not zero.

If you're going to open the file with those options, then you need something like:

```
int fd_i = open(source_file, O_RDONLY);
if (fd_i < 0)
    …report error opening source_file…
FILE *in = fdopen(fd_i, "r");
if (in == 0)
    …report error creating file stream for source_file…

int fd_o = open(target_file, O_CREAT|WRONLY, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH);
if (fd_o < 0)
    …report error opening target_file…
FILE *out = fdopen(fd_o, "w");
if (out == 0)
    …report error creating file stream for target_file…
```

However, I would probably not use [`fdopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopen.html) for the input file — I'd use `fopen()` directly as you did originally — but I might use it for the output file.

Comment: Would chaning the open command to: out = open(target_file, O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH); work as well?

Comment: @user1021170: sorta — it would create the file with the correct permissions, but the file descriptor would be open for reading (you need `O_CREAT|O_WRONLY` or perhaps `O_CREAT|O_RDWR`).  You'd also have a file descriptor instead of a file stream pointer (`int` instead of `FILE *`).  You'd need to either use `fdopen()` to convert the file descriptor into a file stream pointer, or you'd need to change the subsequent code to use I/O calls that use file descriptors instead of file streams.

Comment: I updated my code to reflect your response. Is there anything special I need to do with file stream pointers?

Comment: @user1021170: see the revised answer.